# Delete a specific value from a set of values in a column - HQL

Tags: hql

How can I write a HQL for deleting a specific value from a column ( column contains a set of values separated by comma)

```
Table1
    ID Name Value

    001 Rajesh 90,100,210,400
    002 Suresh 100,400,300,66
    003 Mahesh 200,500
    004 Virat 400,578,57
```

I tried the following code but its wrong.

```
    Session session=getSession();        
   Query query = session.createQuery("delete from Table1 where Value=:Value and Name=:Name");
    query.setParameter("Value", "100");
    query.setParameter("Name", "Rajesh");
    query.executeUpdate();
```

I want to delete value- 100 from Name - Rajesh